# Is there a way of replace null values in a JSON bigquery field?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a **JSON** value like the one below in a certain column of my table:

`{"values":[1, 2, null, 4, null]}`

What I want is to convert the value in a bigquery **ARRAY**: `ARRAY<INT64>`

I tried `JSON_VALUE_ARRAY` but it throws an error because the final output cannot be anarray with NULLs.

Said that, what should be the correct approach for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest an array with null elements. For building a new array you can provided the flag `ignore nulls` to remove null values.

```sql
with tbl as (select JSON '{"values":[1, 2, null, 4, null]}' as data union all select JSON ' {"values":[ ] }')
select *,
((Select array_agg(x ignore nulls) from unnest(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY (data.values ) ) x))

from tbl
```